# Edit values of datagridview of imported excel files

Tags: c#, datagridview

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux6kQ.png)
I use the following code to import excel into datagridview. I want to add rows values to datagriview where excel is imported.

But get this error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first.'
I cannot add columns because I want to edit values of imported excel files which already have columns and rows.

```
string filename = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Book1.xls"; 
string PathConn = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =" + filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes;\";"; 
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathConn); 
OleDbDataAdapter MyDA = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + "expenditure " +"1" + "$]", conn); DataTable dt = new DataTable();
MyDA.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(name1.Text,name2.Text, name3.Text, name4.Text, name5.Text, name6.Text);
```

Comment: Since you are using data binding, add the row to the underlying DataTable.

Comment: I suggest you set a breakpoint after filling the variable `dt` and take a look at `dt` to make sure it actually has columns. Unfortunately, even if `dt` DOES have columns you will get an error when the code attempts to “add” a row to the “grid” programmatically. If you want to “programmatically” add rows to the grid and the grid has a `DataSource`, then, as Tarik states, the code needs to add the new row to the grids `DataSource`… NOT the grid.

Comment: There is no data source, I created a datagridview imported excel in it and want to edit excel in datagridview programmatically, is it possible?

Comment: According to the posted code, the grid DOES have a data source…. `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;`